# How to delete dynamic data binded inside html elements after some event completion in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dom-manipulation

[image]
 Hi , I am uploading documents along with some key word as you can see in the diagram.Here is the code for for inserting key words into the panel which is formed inside a div.

```
<div class="tagListForDocument col-xs-6 col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">{{'TAG.TagsForDocument' | translate}}</div>
        <div class="panel-body btn-group-vertical" role="group" aria-label="available tags">
            <button ng-repeat="tag in ul.tagsForDocuments" ng-click="ul.removeTag(tag)" class="btn btn-flat">
                <span class="icon-remove"></span> {{tag.name}}
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the keywords are formed (`{{tag.name}}`) based on iteration of `ul.tagsForDocuments` array.

Now my problem is that I want to remove all these keywords once the uploading is finished.That means before uploading second time the panel should be empty. But dont know the efficient way of doing this. How can I reload this particular part of html with empty `ul.tagsForDocuments` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you can do:

```
ul.tagsForDocuments = [];
```

which will make the array empty. Angular will then update the view accordingly.